High PREEMPTIVE_OS_QUERYREGISTRY Waits on new SQL Server2022
We have a stack of servers on SQL 2019, and are upgrading them piecemeal to 2022. On the first machine we upgraded, we noticed very high PREEMPTIVE_OS_QUERYREGISTRY waits, where none of the previous machines in the stack (with the same traffic pattern) have any of that wait. I did find the article from MS about the bug regarding azure access policies, and we enabled trace flag 12502. However, we did not see any reduction in this wait with TF12502 enabled, even though we are on CU15 (the latest as of this post). Image below showing the traceflag enabled, our current version, as well as wait stats

Is there anything additional we have to do besides the traceflag to eliminate these waits? Our schema and usage pattern did not change when upgrading from 2019 to 2022, so we did not knowingly introduce any new features that might be accessing the registry. These are on windows server 2022 as well, if that matters. It may also be worth noting that these servers heavily utilize schema-durable in memory tables and in memory OLTP.
Thanks!

Are you able to identify queries, which experience this wait type? Maybe this will give you hint about what is going on?

Please capture an etw trace and share it. Please use the information and answer provided here (I wrote it) for more information: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/341298/broken-query-store

Was the trace flag enabled as a start up parameter? Sometimes they’re tricky like that, and the documentation doesn’t tell you when they take effect.

We haven't restarted the instance since enabling the trace flag - we can try adding as a startup param and cycling the service next time business allows. Thanks for the suggestion

i've seen this wait when we're making lots of remote calls from the db server using linked server. example: EXEC linkedserver.database.dbo.storedproc or EXECUTE('') AT linkedserver. we're using sql server 2019 enterprise. it's not an issue on our side but it might be worth checking on your side if you have linked server calls.

@BenAdams Were you able to find anything further on this? I am seeing the same issue.
